# JsDatePick's data picker appears all broken in appearance in IE8 when used in my page

Tags: internet-explorer-8, datepicker, css

I tried to use [JsDatePick](http://javascriptcalendar.org/) .

The example HTML supplied with the tool ran just fine in both FireFox and IE8

However, when I tried to use the picker in my own HTML page with existing structure and CSS:

- In FireFox it worked fine (the picker appeared as a calendar next to the input field)
- In IE8, the picker apeared as a VERTICAL column of dates, BELOW my page (e.g. you need to scroll down to see it), e.g.

  ```
   ----------------------------------------------
   | My main page DIV, sized ~100% page height  |
   |                                            |
   |                  <INPUT FIELD>             |
   |                                            |
   |                                            |
   |                                            |
   |                                            |
   |                                            |
   |                                            |
   ----------------------------------------------
        ---- BOTTOM OF PAGE HERE ---

                       [1]      <-- This was meant to be a 5x7
                       [2]      <-- calendar pop-up appearing
                       [3]      <-- under the INPUT FIELD
                       [...]    <-- NOTE that the horizontal position is correct,
                       [30]     <-- Fully aligned with INPUT FIELD
  ```

Unfortunately, I'm not enough of a CSS expert to even begin understanding how to troubleshoot it.

1. If anyone used JsDatePick, and ran into this problem, any ideas on how to fix are appreciated
2. Barring that, what would be the steps I need to take to troubleshoot this (Seemingly CSS conflict) problem?

   The page has its own stylesheets but one of them is 100% class-limited styles, 
   while the second one has some global styles, BUT nothing with a position defined, and any styles that are not class specific are font style for `body` and `h1`.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or do you have an online html? IE8 is not too good with percentages, could have something to do with display. Would be essential to check that global css

Comment: @yisela - The global css is not dependent on %s. I'll try to do JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the immediate practical problem for why the picker didn't display correctly.

The example HTML file had the following DTD declaration that I had to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Why the picker would not work in plain HTML is not clear.